# How to change the upload path of the file in the file system?

Tags: php, wordpress, file, filepath, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a custom page template with a custom fill up form using PHP and PHP function, the user can input their basic info and upload a file. This file will upload directly in file system.

Now, I want to rename the file depends on the last and first name of the user, like this lastname_firstname. And also, I want to save the upload files outside the wp-content (let's say on my desktop or a folder outside wp-content) and limit the user what type of file can be upload. How to achieve these?

Here's the PHP snippet how to upload a file in the file system

```
function upload_user_file($file = array()){
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/admin.php');
      $file_return = wp_handle_upload($file, array('test_form' => false));
      if(isset($file_return['error']) || isset($file_return['upload_error_handler'])){
          return false;
      } else {
          $filename = $file_return['file'];
          $attachment = array(
              'post_mime_type' => $file_return['type'],
              'post_title' => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename($filename)),
              'post_content' => '',
              'post_status' => 'inherit',
              'guid' => $file_return['url']
          );

          $attachment_id = wp_insert_attachment($attachment, $file_return['url']);

          require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php');
          $attachment_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata($attachment_id, $filename);
          wp_update_attachment_metadata($attachment_id, $attachment_data);

          if(0 < intval($attachment_id)){
            return $attachment_id;
          }
      }
      return false;
}
```

Comment: Use `move_uploaded_file()` after uploading it.

Answer (score 0):

your problem has been solved using custom code. please replace you function with this script.

firstly you create folder with "static" folder name near wp_content folder. 
then place this code in function.php file.

`

```
function upload_user_file($file = array(), $first_name='',$last_name=''){
   $root= dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(realpath(__FILE__)))));
   $path =$root.'/static/';

    if(!empty($_FILES["file"]["name"])){

            $file_name        = $last_name.'_'.$first_name.$_FILES["file"]["name"];
            $tmp_file     = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
            move_uploaded_file($tmp_file,"$path".$file_name);

    }
}
```

`

Comment: in your code, the `$attachment_id` is missing. `$attachment_id` is important because it will use to get the filename of each files uploaded

Comment: please include `$attachment_id` in your suggestion code

Answer (score -1):

Open your wp-config.php file, locoed at the root of your WordPress installation, and add the following code

```
define('UPLOADS', 'wp-content/myimages');
```

Make sure you add this code before the line

```
require_once(ABSPATH.’wp-settings.php’);
```

If the directory doesn’t already exist, WordPress will automatically create it as long as the wp-content folder is writeable. Otherwise you can great the folder yourself via FTP, cPanel etc

You can also change the way uploads are organized. If you open your uploads folder you’ll notice that files, by default, are sorted into years. You can change your file organization so that all media files are dumped in the one folder. Go to Settings > Media and uncheck “Organize my uploads into month- and year-based folders.”

Not only will it make your URLs simpler, it will also make it easier to see all your files in one place instead of having to sort through month and year directories.

Comment: i don't want to change the path for the whole media/file uploaded. I need is to change the path for the uploaded file from the custom page template.